# C# - Entity Framework error: invalid object name 'dbo.TableName'

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm trying to do a simple data insertion on my database, but I'm getting the follow error: "Invalid Object Name dbo.".

Import(I think) detail... I did basicaly the same code in another test, but I created the table and the db with Sql Management Studio. Now, I just have created in the visual studio using an Empty EF Designer model.

My Insertion code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        using (AlunoModelContainer ctx = new AlunoModelContainer()) { 
            tb_alunos student = new tb_alunos();

        student.nome_aluno = textBox1.Text;
        student.idade_aluno = textBox2.Text;
        student.curso_aluno = textBox4.Text;
        student.endereco_aluno = textBox5.Text;

        ctx.Alunos.Add(student);
        ctx.SaveChanges();
        MessageBox.Show("Estudante cadastrado com sucesso");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Usuário não pôde ser cadastrado." + ex.ToString());
    }

}
```

My db context code:

```
namespace Sistema_Alunos
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

    public partial class AlunoModelContainer : DbContext
    {
        public AlunoModelContainer()
            : base("name=AlunoModelContainer")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public virtual DbSet<tb_alunos> Alunos { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And a simple image of my folder structure:

[image]

Comment: Which table name doesn't exist (on single table or all tables inside DB) and which line throwing error? I see you're attempted Code First Migrations, it may related to table relationships or somewhat called 'pluralization'.

Comment: Put error details which you get and moment when you get it. Also add entity model view.

Comment: Hi friend, today i have got the same error. Table successfully added to database using EF Code First, now I am trying to populate my table but got this same error. Plz reply if you found solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this line to your code.

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
      modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
 }
```

Comment: This is the best answer - no need to change names

Answer (score 0):

Your partial class tb_alunos does not have [Table("tb_alunos")] attribute so it cannot be mapped to the table of the database .

Try this :

```
 [Table("tb_alunos")]
public partial class tb_alunos
{
    public int alunoID { get; set; }
    public string nome_aluno { get; set; }
    public string curso_aluno { get; set; }
    public string endereco_aluno { get; set; }
    public string idade__aluno { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: in EF we only need to add table attribute if out table name is different in Database. So i don't think this is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this problem. I have got same problem. I have created table called `SubscriptionType` but while creating table by convention Entity Framework added extra "S" at the end of table name and it became `SubscriptionTypes`.

So match your table name in database and in your model class.